# Как можно в Symfony проверть текущего пользователя?

Tags: php, symfony

Изучаю Symfony и делаю личный кабинет пользователя.

Например есть такой адрес `/{userId}/cabinet` и я хочу что бы доступ в кабинет получал только тот юзер который авторизован и у которого id совпадает с `userId`

На текущий момент делаю простую проверку `if($userId == $this->getUser()->getId())`

Но методов довольно много и везде пихать эту проверку не удобно, мб мoжно как нибудь получше это дело реализовать, как например мидлвары у ларавель?

Comment: Можно сделать voter. Можно поискать какое-нибудь событие.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал про такое) Почитаю

Comment: Можете инжектить свой сервис, в котором будет один метод isOwner($userId), который под капотом будет инжектить Security и выполнять проверку

Comment: Либо добавить event listener который будет это проверять и бросать access denied